# How to use SelectToken() when a property name contains indexer characters []

Tags: json.net, jsonpath

Trying to edit a JSON object, I have to get to a specific node.
I am using something like:

```
root.SelectToken("dot.delimited.path.to.node")
```

and it works fine until a node has a property name like `"vectorOne[1]"`.

Is there a way to 'escape' the [] characters in SelectToken()? if not- can someone please advice?

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), like sharing a sample json, sharing related code, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [original JSONPath proposal](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/), you can use bracket notation as well as dot notation for accessing properties by name:

> JSONPath expressions can use the *dot*–notation
>
> `$.store.book[0].title`
>
> or the *bracket*–notation
>
> `$['store']['book'][0]['title']`

Thus, using [`SelectToken()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectToken.htm), you may access a property named `"vectorOne[1]"` via `['vectorOne[1]']`.  E.g., if your JSON looks like:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "vectorOne[1]": {
      "value": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Then

```
root.SelectToken("data['vectorOne[1]'].value")
```

Will select the value `1`.

Notes:

- If the property name contains an single-quote character, it can be escaped with a `\`, e.g. if you have the following JSON:

  ```json
  {
    "single-quote-'": "value"
  }
  ```

  Then you may select the `"single-quote-'"` by using the following path:

  ```
  root.SelectToken(@"['single-quote-\'']");
  ```

  (Be careful not to confuse c# string escaping, which is evaluated at compile time, with JSONPath string escaping, which is evaluated at runtime.)
- If you are uncertain of the path to use for any specific value, you can iterate through all the descendants of a `JObject` using [`JContainer.DescendantsAndSelf()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_DescendantsAndSelf.htm) and print their paths via [`JToken.Path`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Path.htm):

  ```
   foreach (var item in root.DescendantsAndSelf())
       Console.WriteLine(item.Path);
  ```
- See also the documentation page [Querying JSON with JSON Path and escaped properties](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenEscaped.htm).

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/azLUqY).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.
In my current context, I am receiving a string array of the nodes that I have to update, or in another case- create. I cannot assume anything about the array, nor I know the structure of the JSON tree to update.  
So finally, I decided to write a simple component, that will replace '[' and ']' in the node name, when I have to work on the JSON object, then replace back on serialization.